# Pick up two numbers from an array so that the sum is a constant

Tags: c#, algorithm

I came across an algorithm problem. Suppose I receive a credit and would like to but two items from a local store. I would like to buy two items that add up to the entire value of the credit. The input data has three lines.

The first line is the credit, the second line is the total amount of the items and the third line lists all the item price.

Sample data 1:

```
200
7
150 24 79 50 88 345 3
```

Which means I have $200 to buy two items, there are 7 items. I should buy item 1 and item 4 as `200=150+50`

Sample data 2:

```
8
8
2 1 9 4 4 56 90 3
```

Which indicates that I have $8 to pick two items from total 8 articles. The answer is item 4 and item 5 because `8=4+4`

My thought is first to create the array of course, then pick up any item say item x. Creating another array say "remain" which removes x from the original array.

Subtract the price of x from the credit to get the remnant and check whether the "remain" contains remnant.

Here is my code in C#.

```
        // Read lines from input file and create array price
        foreach (string s in price)
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse(s);
            string y = (credit - x).ToString();

            index1 = Array.IndexOf(price, s) ;
            index2 = Array.IndexOf(price, y) ;
            remain = price.ToList();
            remain.RemoveAt(index1);//remove an element
            if (remain.Contains(y))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        // return something....
```

My two questions:

1. How is the complexity? I think it is O(n2).
2. Any improvement to the algorithm? When I use sample 2, I have trouble to get correct indices. Because there two "4" in the array, it always returns the first index since IndexOf(String) reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply sort the array in `O(nlogn)` time. Then for each element `A[i]` conduct a binary search for `S-A[i]` again in `O(nlogn)` time.

EDIT: As pointed out by Heuster, you can solve the 2-SUM problem on the sorted array in linear time by using two pointers (one from the beginning and other from the end).

Comment: Or even better: after sorting, start from both ends of the array. If the sum is too high: step back with the higher value. If the sum is too low: step forward with the lower value.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `HashSet<int>` of the prices. Then go through it sequentially.Something like:

```
HashSet<int> items = new HashSet<int>(itemsList);

int price1 = -1;
int price2 = -1;
foreach (int price in items)
{
    int otherPrice = 200 - price;
    if (items.Contains(otherPrice))
    {
        // found a match.
        price1 = price;
        price2 = otherPrice;
        break;
    }
}
if (price2 != -1)
{
    // found a match.
    // price1 and price2 contain the values that add up to your target.
    // now remove the items from the HashSet
    items.Remove(price1);
    items.Remove(price2);
}
```

This is O(n) to create the `HashSet`. Because lookups in the `HashSet` are O(1), the `foreach` loop is O(n).

Comment: The thing is that // found a mtach??? How? It takes time by different algorithm. items always contains otherPrice.

Comment: Is it fast than 2-sum?

Comment: @Love: With a large number of items, doing hash table lookups will likely be faster than sorting and then using the 2-sum algorithm. With a small list, the overhead of the hash table will likely cause it to be slower.

Comment: This array `int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };` could not be correctly figure out.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called 2-sum. See., for example, http://coderevisited.com/2-sum-problem/

Comment: Thanks Irit, it is my first time to know this term.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm in O(N) time complexity and O(N) space : -

```
1. Put all numbers in hash table.
2. for each number Arr[i] find Sum - Arr[i] in hash table in O(1)
3. If found then (Arr[i],Sum-Arr[i]) are your pair that add up to Sum
```

**Note:-** Only failing case can be when Arr[i] = Sum/2 then you can get false positive but you can always check if there are two Sum/2 in the array in O(N)

Comment: The thing is that there might existing the duplicate price in the list. I worry about it via using hash table as the same key. Say sample 2 I provided, there are two "4".

Comment: @Love There can be only one such case that is Sum = Arr[i]*2 for which there is simple solution read my Note

Answer (score 0):

I know I am posting this is a year and a half later, but I just happened to come across this problem and wanted to add input.

If there exists a solution, then you know that both values in the solution must both be less than the target sum.

1. Perform a binary search in the array of values, searching for the target sum (which may or may not be there).
2. The binary search will end with either finding the sum, or the closest value less than sum. That is your starting high value while searching through the array using the previously mentioned solutions. Any value above your new starting high value cannot be in the solution, as it is more than the target value.

   3. At this point, you have eliminated a chunk of data in log(n) time, that would otherwise be eliminated in O(n) time.

Again, this is an optimization that may only be worth implementing if the data set calls for it.